# Making android public storage folder visible/browsable

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I'm now updating an old app for Andrdoid 4.4 and the issue I ran into was the change in access to the external storage. I've fixed it so that it uses the new app folder sdcard/Android/data/my.app.package/files in the sdcard.

My problem is that for some reason the sdcard/Android/data/my.app.package folder, despite existing and being accessible via adb, is not seen when I'm browsing the data from the computer, e.g. via Android File Transfer or just via the computer file explorer. All the other app folders are visible, except mine. Does anyone know what do I need to fix?

Comment: `sdcard/Android/data/my.app.package/files `. Think you mean `/sdcard/Android/data/my.app.package/files`. Which protocol does the computer use? MTP? Then your files will not be scanned by the mediastore yet.

Comment: Yes, /sdcard and yes it uses MTP. When will the files be scanned then? What's strange is that other the older folders for the other apps all show up...

Comment: Mostly they will be scanned at reboot. But you better tell the media scanner to scan your file right after you created one.